# Best way to redirect to non-www AND enforce SSL at the same time

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I created a way to redirect www to non-www and to redirect any http to https. However, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant and efficient way to do this. Here's my code:

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite all http to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://{HTTP_HOST}.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce non-www and https using a single RewriteRule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

The combination of OR and AND conditions above allows us to manipulate  2 types of requests at one time 1) http www, 2) https www and The  rule always redirects them to the ssl non-www version. You can Replace R with R=301 to make the Redirect Permanent.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to enforce a non-www. In order to do that, I'm figuring that I change the second condition to 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.' However, I'm not sure about the third condition. Do I just leave it as is?

Comment: Both answers are valuable. Not sure why you edited instead of also showing how to enforce www with SSL at the same time. Revision history to the rescue :-)